# nginx mirror traffic configuration issues

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to mirror the SNMP trap across multiple servers. It uses TCP/IP traffic. I am using nginx to complete this but i am getting the following error

```
vsrsadmin@TRAP02:~$ sudo nginx -t

nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:118

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

```
stream{
upstream dns_servers {
least_conn;
server 192.168.49.19:162 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
}

upstream mir_dns_servers {
least_conn;
server 192.168.49.15:162 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
}
#}

server {
listen 162;
# proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
# proxy_pass dns_servers;

location / {
mirror /mirror;
mirror_request_body on;
proxy_pass dns_servers;
}

location = /mirror {
mirror /mirror;
mirror_request_body on;
proxy_pass mir_dns_servers;
proxy_connect_timeout 200ms;
proxy_read_timeout 200ms;
```

Answer (score 0):

`stream` is meant for relaying raw TCP traffic.

`ngx_http_mirror_module` is meant for mirroring HTTP requests to a different destination.

Raw TCP traffic does not contain HTTP traffic, so therefore `mirror` module cannot be used with it.

I don't think nginx can be used for the mirror operation you are trying to perform. I don't know if there is any tool for your objective.

Comment: Is there any other tool i can use to mirror the Traffice that is not HTTP?

Comment: is there any way to mirror tcp traffic like snmp trap?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the configuration file seems to be that the "location" directive is placed inside the "stream" context. The "location" directive is only applicable in the "http" context, so it cannot be used in the "stream" context.

But you can move the "location" directive inside an "http" block, and see what happens.